# CSS - Resize both

Tags: css, resize

Boa tarde.

Estou usando a propriedade resize:both em uma div e funciona perfeitamente, a minha duvida é referente aos dois tracinhos que aparecem para indicar tal propriedade, é possível customização dos mesmos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não consegue customizar ele.

Uma alternativa é você colocar uma imagem no canto inferior direito, usando algum código do tipo, acima dos "tracinhos":

```
    textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff url(http://merchantmomphotoeditor.com/pixenate/docs/resize_handle2.gif) 100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Show, obrigado.